# Unable to import pyperclip on IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to import pyperclip on IDLE but unable to do so and getting the error :

```py
>>> import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'"
```

I went to cmd, ran as administrator, moved to the path using - `cd \Program Files\Python37\Scripts` and downloaded pip via `pip3 install pyperclip` command and it is successfully downloaded and message displayed as

> Requirement already satisfied: Pyperclip in c:\program files\python37 (1.7.0)

I went back to IDLE interactive shell window and again gave the command `import pyperclip` and it throws an error :-

```py
>>> import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Please help ??

Comment: I'd guess that IDLE is linked to python 2. What does `import sys; print(sys.version)` show (from IDLE)?

Comment: Holloway :- This is what it shows ">>> import sys; print (sys.version)
3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] "

Answer (score 0):

Go to your python directory and sub-directory and run `pip.exe` from there. It seems you are using `pip.exe` for some other installation. so go to "`<python_installation_directory>/Scripts/pip.exe install pyperclip"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the IDLE 64bit instead of the 32bit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).